# Algorithm that returns sets of vertices that are equal distance (not infinite) by a Vertex

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-graph, breadth-first-search

Write an algorithm that, given a graph G and a vertex t of G, returns
sets of vertices that are equal distance (not infinite) by t.

The graph G is the following:

[image]

Considering t = A, the algorithm should return:

- Set of vertices at distance 0: {A}
- Set of vertices at distance 1: {B, D}
- Set of vertices at distance 2: {E, F}
- Set of vertices at distance 3: {C}
- Set of vertices at distance 4: {}
- Set of vertices at distance 5: {}

I think that the algorithm can be realized with a simple modification of the algorithm of breadth which summarizes the distance of all the vertices from the source vertex.
How can I write the pseudocode? I'm a bit confused..

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes you can use `BFS` to solve the problem by storing the distance to each Node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following pseudo-code: ( you can save the distance from the source node in BFS by setting the distance property of each node to father.distance + 1, and the initial node has a distance of 0. also the initial distance for every node is infinite)

```
 BFS(G,targetNode), remember to save all the distances for each node.

 for i = 0 to G.v.size

     print "nodes with distance i :"

     for each Vertex v in G:

         if v.distance == i

             print v
```